# d3 append whitespace after appended div

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have following code:

```
 this.other.selectAll('div').data(this.words).call(function(){
    this.enter().append('div').each(function() {
    ...
```

This creates a structure where divs are along each other, like

```
<div></div><div></div>
```

But I want them space separated

```
<div></div> <div></div>
```

to work with (for container)

```
text-align: justify;
```

I have for divs

```
display: inline-block;
```

How to insert these spaces nicely?

---

So far I have a solution with jquery, but I am really interested to know how to do it in d3

Comment: The short answer is that you can't without horrible hacks. You could however append an empty `div` that you give a certain width after each `div`.

Comment: I need justify, so constant width is not an option

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, the extra white space could be achieved with a pseudo element. E.g: `div::after { content:''; width:5px; display:inline-block; }` or something like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `.each` you can tap into the list of elements and simply add a space before each `span`:

```
this.other.selectAll('div').data(this.words).call(function(){
  this.enter().append('div').each(function() {
    if (this.previousSibling && previousSibling.nodeValue == ' ') {
      return;  // Already have a space before this span, don't add another.
    }

    this.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', ' ')
  });
...
```

Another option is to use the `::after` pseudo-element and a [non-breaking space character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space):

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
div::after {
  content: '\00a0';  // Non-breaking space.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ::after pseudo element didn't do it for me. So I did one of the above mentioned "horrible hacks", which I'd like to share just for completeness of this thread:

```
let div = d3.select('#footer')
div.html(div.html().replace(/<\/div><div>/gi, '</div> <div>'))
```

And it did exactly what was asked here ;)